# Declaring 2-dimensional array in "Edit distance" on spoj locally gives runtime error?

Tags: c++, arrays

While solving http://www.spoj.com/problems/EDIST/ , when I declare the 2-d array globally: (http://ideone.com/jG3jPW)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long int s[2001][2001];

int main() {
int t;
string a,b;
long long int i,j;
for(i=0;i<2001;i++)
{
    s[i][0]=i;
    s[0][i]=i;
}
cin>>t;
while(t>0)
{
    cin>>a>>b;
    t--;
    for(i=1;i<=a.length();i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=b.length();j++)
        {
            if(a[i-1] == b[j-1])
                s[i][j]=s[i-1][j-1];
            else
                s[i][j] = min(min(s[i-1][j],s[i-1][j-1]),s[i][j-1]) + 1;
        }
    }
    cout<<s[i-1][j-1]<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

no error occurs. But when i declare the same array locally(http://ideone.com/Tyj6UU),

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
int t;
string a,b;
long long int i,j;

long long int s[2001][2001]; //declared locally

for(i=0;i<2001;i++)
{
    s[i][0]=i;
    s[0][i]=i;
}
cin>>t;
while(t>0)
{
    cin>>a>>b;
    t--;
    for(i=1;i<=a.length();i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=b.length();j++)
        {
            if(a[i-1] == b[j-1])
                s[i][j]=s[i-1][j-1];
            else
                s[i][j] = min(min(s[i-1][j],s[i-1][j-1]),s[i][j-1]) + 1;
        }
    }
    cout<<s[i-1][j-1]<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

runtime error occurs. Why?

Comment: Hint: what is the name of this website?

Comment: Hint: use a `std::vector` so you only need as much space as required and you use dynamic memory allocation which generally is a much bigger pool of memory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are having some kind of problem with memory allocation.

In your second approach (i.e., the one with local declaration), change:

```
long long int s[2001][2001];
```

To:

```
long long int ** s = new long long int * [2001];
for (i=0;i<2001;i++)
    s[i] = new long long int[2001];
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: but why using an array is causing error in memory allocation? i wanted to know the exact problem.